# Should paginated sites be included in sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, search-engine-indexing, pagination

My website is ad listing for boats, boats' engines, boat rentals, etc (`www.mynautics.com`).

There are ads listed on multiple pages. I have finished (not jet seen on link above) pagination:

- added `prev`
- added `next`

On some pages (sorting, etc.) I also added canonical relation.

Now I want to add pages to sitemap generator and I am not sure if I should add all URLs for example:

- `example.com/list/page/1`
- `example.com/list/page/2`
- `example.com/list/page/3`
- `example.com/list/page/4`

Or should I just add `example.com/list`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include to your sitemap all the URLs you want to see in a search engine's index.

Comment: I thought so but was not sure due to pagination stuff! Thanks for your answer!