# Can i put pagination URL on sitemap?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I read here https://blog.spotibo.com/sitemap-guide/ on the section "Which URLs should be put in a sitemap" that i should exclude Paginated Pages, i seached it on google and i did'nt found a person saying that i should'nt, i also don't found a person saying that i should, so i'm kinda confused.

The content from my paginated pages is unique and i'ts can only be accessable with the url https://example.com/?p=some-item&page=2..3..4..etc, there's only one item in this page, and only the first item can be accessable with the url https://example.com/?p=some-item

**I want to know**: can i put these URL on sitemap?

Comment: I always recommend getting rid of pagination.   1% of users typically access page 2+.   Search engines usually choose not to index pages 2+.   There are much better solutions for both users (search, dimensional navigation) and for SEO (linking product pages to other product pages).   List 100 products on page 1 and provide other ways to get to the other products.

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59542/should-paginated-sites-be-included-in-sitemap

Comment: Related?  It looks like an exact duplicate to me.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Nice this answear my question.